# Wrong page numbering for TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

For the MWE below:

```
\title{TITLE} 

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% TITLE PAGE %%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\maketitle %Title page

%make an empty page
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{abstract}
\noindent
abstract
\end{abstract}

\newpage

\thispagestyle{empty} %Empty page

\begin{center}
\vspace*{10cm}
Some acknowledgment
\end{center}

\vspace*{3.5cm} %space so that page stays empty

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% For header and footers %%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
% Clear the default
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{\thepage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% CONTENTS PAGE 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\begin{spacing}{1.0}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents
\end{spacing}
\newpage

\end{document}
```

Why does the title page starts from II instead of I ? It was fine until I added the part `%make an empty page`. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `\clearpage` as in

```
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\clearpage  %%% here
\setcounter{page}{1}
```